# where are the qt-creator plugin TabbedEditor dependent libs?

Tags: qt, plugins, qt-creator

**I downloaded a tab plugin for qt-creator, called "TabbedEditor". It needs two dependent libs. Where can I get them?** 
-- warning message:

> Could not resolve dependency 'Core(3.0.0)' Could not resolve
>   dependency 'TextEditor(3.0.0)'

thank you

Answer (score 2):

The "TextEditor" is part of the Qt Creator core. You already have it (check with About->Plugins), but likely not the 3.0.0 version this "TabbedEditor" plugin requires.

Comment: Thanks. The plugin is probably needed to be recompiled against my latest qt-creator libs.